# EZPLOT not giving the right answer

Tags: matlab

I'm using EZPLOT for drawing a coupler curve and I got a weird plot. If I have f=x^2 + y^2 - 1
I get a nic e circle, but if I write f=(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2 I don't get a thing. Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you writing? I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should add your code to the post, so we are able to relate to your problem.

Comment: @Daniel: I simply did `figure; ezplot('x^2 + y^2 - 1'); figure; ezplot('(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2');` and I reproduced the problem.

Comment: The code doesn't really matter, it was a function for getting Coupler curve F(x,y)=0 and drawing it. This problem happens any way with no code attached. If the code is needed I will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is because in the first case, `ezplot` is actually plotting:

```
x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0
```

This will give you a circular plot.

In your second case, you are actually plotting

```
(x^2 + y^2 - 1)^2 = 0
```

In this case, there are **no solutions** to this equation, which is why you have a blank plot.  This actually makes sense.  If you take the square root of both sides, we get:

```
x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0

      AND

-(x^2 + y^2 - 1) = 0
```

You have a system of two equations which actually conflict with each other.  Even though you can intuitively substitute `(x,y)` values into the equation and solve for `0`, `ezplot` doesn't know this.  As an experiment, try raising the equation to any `odd` power and you will see that `ezplot` can produce a plot.  Try doing `^3, ^5` etc.

Comment: It doesn't conflict, what are the x and y values that answer -(x^2 + y^2 - 1) = 0 other than (x^2 + y^2 - 1) = 0? If I have a long equation how do I know if matlab is doing something like this?

Comment: You could always define a `meshgrid` of points and plot it manually.  Don't know what to do tell you.  That's the only explanation that I can think of.  It could be the fact that equations with `^2` terms usually have two solutions in general and `ezplot` can't plot those.  I don't know the internals.  If you want my advice, don't plot anything with `^2` :)